# How to edit the text of the Grub menu's options?

Tags: grub2, customization

Every Grub menu have its options written is English and I would like to translate it to Portuguese.
So, this is the question, how to edit the text of the Grub menu's options?

For example the 12.10 Grub's menu is something like that:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced Ubuntu options
```

My objective is to translate it to:

```
Ubuntu
Opções avançadas do Ubuntu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Before doing anything, make a backup copy of the file you are going to edit, just in case*.

There is a `grub.cfg` file located in `/boot/grub/`.

The grub menu entries are listed there. Each entry starts with `menuentry` word, which is followed by the entry text in single or double quotation marks.

Everything that is inside the single quotes is the text that is displayed for that entry.

You also might want to take a look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1287602) on ubuntuforums.

Comment: just an enhancement: instead of editing `grub.cfg` its better to edit the files in `/etc/grub.d` folder, because `grub.cfg` is automatically generated using those files when the grub entries need to be updated (ex: installing a new kernel)